# FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'C://tgplay/123_business.py'

Tags: python, файлы, telebot

Я сделал функцию покупки игрового бизнеса. Код:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == 'Бизнес купить 1':
        # проверка денег(баланса)
        File = open('c://tgplay/{0}_money.py'.format(message.chat.id), 'r')
        isset_money = int(File.read())
        File.close


        if not (str(message.chat.id)+'_business.py') in 'C://tgplay': # если файл не существует:
            if isset_money >= int(5000):
                File = open('C://tgplay/{0}_business.py'.format(message.chat.id), 'x+')
                File.write('BALANCE = 1')
                File.close
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы успешно купили бизнес "Продажа самоделок"!')
                bot.send_message(123, 'Игрок ' + str(message.chat.id) + ' купил бизнес.')
            elif isset_money < int(5000): # если в файле money недостаточно денег:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Недостаточно средств!')
        else: # если файл business уже существует:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка. У вас уже есть бизнес!')
```

Но выдаёт ошибку при тестировании команды, т.е. он не видит `else` и всё равно пытается создать файл business.

Где ошибка в моём коде?

UPD: да, я знаю что когда пользователь покупает бизнес, у него не вычитаются деньги

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данной строке кода:

```
if not (str(message.chat.id)+'_business.py') in 'C://tgplay'
```

вы делаете проверку на отсутствие подстроки `str(message.chat.id)+'_business.py'` в строке `'C://tgplay'`. Очевидно это условие будет выполняться всегда для любого значения `message.chat.id`.

Если вы хотите проверить существует ли соответствующий файл, то это можно сделать так:

```
import os.path

if os.path.isfile(f"C://tgplay/{message.chat.id}_business.py"):
    ...
```

чтобы проверить, что файл **не существует**:

```
if not os.path.isfile(f"C://tgplay/{message.chat.id}_business.py"):
    ...
```

Comment: Помогло, но теперь он сосредоточен на else... Видео: https://radikal.ru/video/A3q6090AD4z

Comment: @str, данный ответ отвечает на сформулированный в [вашем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1315106/211923) вопрос. Откройте новый SO вопрос, если у вас возник новый вопрос